# How to fix UnsatisfiedLinkError by making minimal changes?

Tags: gcc, java-native-interface, javac, rhel, .so

I am trying to compile and run the following JNI Java file in RHEL:

```
package com.isprint.am.util.hsm;

public class LunaMDUtil {

    //bunch of constants

    public native int MD_Initialize();
    //...and a bunch of other native methods

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("ethsm");
        System.loadLibrary("LunaMDUtil");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // some test code code
    }

}
```

(I omitted the code because I think it is not relevant to the question.)

In my dev folder I have the following files:

```
// files used to build libLunaMDUtil.so
com_isprint_am_util_hsm_LunaMDUtil.c
com_isprint_am_util_hsm_LunaMDUtil.h
ethsm.lib

libLunaMDUtil.so

LunaMDUtil.java (i.e the above Java source code file)
```

To build `libLunaMDUtil.so` I run the following command:

```
gcc -fPIC -I"$JAVA_HOME/include" -I"$JAVA_HOME/include/linux" -shared -o libLunaMDUtil.so com_isprint_am_util_hsm_LunaMDUtil.c
```

No errors here. Next I compile my `LunaMDUtil.java`:

```
javac -cp . LunaMDUtil.java
```

No errors here. The final step here is where I start getting problems.

Running `java -Xdiag -cp . LunaMDUtil` gives me this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class LunaMDUtil
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LunaMDUtil (wrong name: com/isprint/am/util/hsm/LunaMDUtil)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
```

Next, I run `java -Xdiag -cp . com.isprint.am.util.hsm.LunaMDUtil` and I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.isprint.am.util.hsm.LunaMDUtil
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.isprint.am.util.hsm.LunaMDUtil
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
```

I move my .class file to folder `./com/isprint/am/util/hsm` (following the package name) and this time I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ethsm in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at com.isprint.am.util.hsm.LunaMDUtil.<clinit>(LunaMDUtil.java:67)
```

At this point my hands start to become tied because `ethsm.lib` is a library from an external party and I would like to avoid renaming it if possible. Also, I would like to avoid making source code changes if possible. (Of course if the one and only solution involves making those changes then at least I have some justification.)

What changes should I make so that I can get my test code in `LunaMDUtil.java` to run?

Comment: Is `ethsm` really a JNI library? Or just something that `LunaMDUtil` depends on? If the latter, you should not attempt to load it at all.

Comment: @user207421 `ethsm` is not a JNI library, instead it contains functions that my C source file calls

Comment: Exactly, so don't try to load it as a JNI library. And if it is a .lib your C code is already statically linked to it; otherwise if it is a .so your C code is already dynamically linked to it. You don't need to do any more.

Comment: @user207421 - "if it is a .so your C code is already dynamically linked to it. You don't need to do any more." - I am afraid it's not quite true. It depends on system, but linking to `.so` is not enough. You have to make sure that `.so` you are linking to is either on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or you link with `-rpath`. Otherwise, system will not see the lib. `java.library.path` is valid only for libraries loaded using `loadLibrary` and not for other libs this library depend on. In Windows, this library has to be on `PATH`.

Comment: @Oo.oO Please pay attention to the context. It is enough in terms of linking and loading. You don't have to try to load it as a JNI library when it isn't. *Of course* the .so has to be present at runtime, this goes without saying. And I have not said one word about `java.library.path`. Don't put words into my mouth.

Comment: @user207421- I am not, and I never was putting words into your mouth. This was just a remark related to "loadLibrary" - where `java.library.path` is used. I never said that you have said `java.library.path`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have following static code

```
System.loadLibrary("ethsm");
```

It will load `libethsm.so` library. You have to make sure it exists.

You say that `ethsm.lib` comes from external developer. In that case, use this function instead

```
String path = "/this/is/path/to/your/ethsm/";
System.load(path + "ethsm.lib");
```

This way, library will be loaded from the file as specified in `load`.

Alternatively, you can always create symbolic link:

```
ln -s ethsm.lib libethsm.so
```

However, this will only work for shared libraries.

**Linking with shared library and not loading it in Java**

If you have shared library (e.g.: `libethsm.so`) you can always link your code with this library

```
gcc -fPIC -I"$JAVA_HOME/include" \
  -I"$JAVA_HOME/include/linux" \
  -L$(ETHSM_LOCATION) 
  -lethsm 
  -shared -o libLunaMDUtil.so com_isprint_am_util_hsm_LunaMDUtil.c
```

however, this will require putting this lib on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or linking with `-rpath`.

You can find sample here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-023/

**Linking with static library and not loading it in Java**

If your library turns out to be a static library, you can always link it with your code while compiling your `JNI` code

```
gcc -fPIC -I"$JAVA_HOME/include" \
  -I"$JAVA_HOME/include/linux" \
  -shared -o libLunaMDUtil.so \
  com_isprint_am_util_hsm_LunaMDUtil.c \
  ethsm.lib
```

You can find sample here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-059/

**Putting library directly into shared lib - if you have source code**

If you have source code, you can simply put both: `JNI` and source code of lib inside `JNI` based library

You can find sample here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-021/

Comment: This is strange. In case of `load` you should get different error: `Can't load library:` if the file is missing.

Comment: He should get an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`, and he is. The actual text is platform-dependent. Your code doesn't accomplish anything by absolute-ising the current working directory.

Comment: @user207421 - Thanks for your remarks and lifting up my answer :) Thanks for being awesome :)